# Adding Fire and Forget Step in Oracle Data Integrator Tool

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have added a Scenario to a Load plan which runs a Procedure and is independent of other steps in the Load plan. I want to make this as a Fire and Forget Step so that rest all the steps will run with out waiting for it to complete. How can i make it as Fire and Forget Step?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Parallel` parent step with your standalone scenario as one of the children so that the other steps will not have to wait for it to end.

See the following screenshot:

[image: example]

Comment: The step should get completed as soon as it started but the Scenario needs to run in the background. There is a dependency on this Loadplan, untill it gets completed the other Loadplans will wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the Step as Package with Asynchronous mode which is working as I want.